# Finding a particular Maven Dependency for a class

Tags: maven

I am trying to determine what the Maven dependency would look like in order to use the following Class:

```
com.sun.xml.bind.IDResolver
```

Can anyone point me to where I can find the dependency? I tried the following, but Eclipse still doesn't know what class IDResolver is referencing.

```
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
          <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
          <version>2.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: That looks fine, the artifact exists at those co-ordinates in Maven Central: http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-impl/2.0.5/ .  Actually, there is a more modern version 2.2.7 published, as per http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-impl .  Perhaps you have an m2e / Eclipse problem instead?  Is the artifact definitely not in your local repository?

Comment: What is the error that you are getting. Can it not find `IDResolver`, or can it not find one if the dependencies that `IDResolver` needs?